# Replacing a .xml file within jar

Tags: java, xml, jar

I am trying to make changes to an xml file stored within a jar file in Java.

My program reads the xml file from the jar, makes a few changes to it using:

```
javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder
javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
org.w3c.dom.Document;
```

This works without any issues.  I then write those changes to a new xml file using the following lines of code:

```html
  TransformerFactory transFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
  Transformer trans = transFactory.newTransformer();
  DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
  File tempStorage = new File("/some/directory/config.xml");
  StreamResult result = new StreamResult(tempStorage);
  trans.transform(source, result);
```

Which works perfectly.  After this, I add the xml file into the jar using the following  console command:

```
jar uf jarFile.jar "/some/directory/name.xml"
```

This adds the xml file into the jar within the directory specified.  I want to add it to the base directory of the jar.  For example, when I unpack the jar I want the folder structure to be this:

```
jarFolder/config.xml
```

NOT

```
jarFolder/some/directory/config.xml
```

Replacing the temp storage directory with just "config.xml" does not work, as I am running the program through eclipse, and it stores the file as:

```
jarFolder/eclipse/directory/eclipse.app
```

Ideally I want to keep the config file within the jar so I don't have a bunch of loose files associated with my program, and can simply read config.xml without having to check for loose files created from running the program previously.  I should also mention that config.xml is already stored in the jar to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try mentioning the directory as below.  The `-C` option helps you specify the target directory where you want the file.

```
jar uf jarFile.jar -C . "/some/directory/name.xml"
```